# Red Black Tree Property

Tags: data-structures, red-black-trees

Although it may sound trivial...

I was going trough the definitions for Red Black Tree in the book "Introduction to Algorithms" and I still cannot understand, why this is not a RBT?

```
    B
  /   \
 B     B
/ \   / \
n  n  n  n
```

Comparing to the properties of a RBT:
It should satisfy all of them...?

Comment: Who says this isn't a red-black tree?

Comment: Looks like a proper red black tree to me, unless 'B' means 'red' rather than 'black'

Comment: You said it yourself, it satisfies the properties.

Comment: There are a lot of books with the title "Introduction to Algorithms" which one are you referring to and which section / chapter / page are you talking about?